# How to configure k8s ingress to work with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, react-router-dom, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm using `react-router-dom` to capture parameters from a url on my website, however everytime I try reaching my ending point at `www.mywebsite.com/video/id` I get a 404 response from my nginx ingress. I've configured it to point the incoming request to my frontend deployment appropriately but otherwise I don't know why the configuration isn't working properly:

My Ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: ingress-service
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
        kubecnginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'

spec:
    tls:
        - hosts:
            - website.app
            - www.website.app
          secretName: website-app
    rules:
        - host: website.app
          http:
            paths:
                - path: /
                  backend:
                    serviceName: frontend-cluster-ip-service
                    servicePort: 3000
                - path: /video/*
                  backend:
                    serviceName: frontend-cluster-ip-service
                    servicePort: 3000
                - path: /api/
                  backend:
                    serviceName: backend-cluster-ip-service
                    servicePort: 5000
                - path: /payments/
                  backend:
                    serviceName: backend-cluster-ip-service
                    servicePort: 5000
                - path: /streaming/
                  backend:
                    serviceName: streaming-ip-service
                    servicePort: 3000
        - host: www.website.app
          http:
            paths:
                - path: /
                  backend:
                    serviceName: frontend-cluster-ip-service
                    servicePort: 3000
                - path: /video/*
                  backend:
                    serviceName: frontend-cluster-ip-service
                    servicePort: 3000
                - path: /api/
                  backend:
                    serviceName: backend-cluster-ip-service
                    servicePort: 5000
                - path: /payments/
                  backend:
                    serviceName: backend-cluster-ip-service
                    servicePort: 5000
                - path: /streaming/
                  backend:
                    serviceName: streaming-ip-service
                    servicePort: 3000
```

React code:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <RecoilRoot>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
    <Route exact path="/video/:id" component={Video}/>
  </Switch>
</Router>
      </React.Suspense>
    </RecoilRoot>
    </div>
  );
}
```

UPDATE:

Jonas' answer does indeed fix the problem on the k8s ingress side, however the docker container actually running the react application must have its nginx.conf updated to work with `react-router-dom`. I provide the appropriate `Dockerfile` and `nginx/nginx.conf` (top level directory of your application) files below (courtesy of [source](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/dockerizing-a-react-application-using-nginx-and-react-router-43154cc8e58c)):

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
RUN yarn add react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN yarn run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**nginx/nginx.conf:**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't want to use *exact match* on `path:`, you probably want to enable [regex path matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/) by adding an annotation:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

And then change your path:

```
path: /video/*
```

to

```
path: /video/.*
```

or something more specific matching your `/id` pattern.

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me :( i get 404 for everything now